# Show that if $f(x)$ and $f '(x)$ are not coprime, $f(x)$ must have a multiple factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Suppose $f(x)$ is in $F[x]$, $F$ a field, and the characteristic of $F$ does not divide the degree of $f (x)$. Show that if $f (x)$ and $f'(x)$ are not coprime, $f (x)$ must have a multiple factor.

I am supposed to use the fact that $f'(x)\ne 0 $ but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: By multiple factor, you mean a repeated root in the algebraic closure of $F$? If so, just take a root of the common divisor of $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: How do I find the common divisor of f and f'? Should I just call it x ?

Comment: Well, $x$ is your variable, so you can't call it $x$. The common divisor is some (non-zero, non-unit) polynomial - call it $d$, if you like.

Comment: I understand that f(x) has multiplie roots then d >1. I am unsure of how to do this in the other direction because I cannot see the connection with the characteristic of  the field.

Comment: By multiple factor, you mean a repeated irreducible factor?

Comment: This is an exercise in Childs' book.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ be a common irreducible factor of $f$ and $f'$.

Write $f=q g$.

Now $q$ divides $f'=q g' + q'g$, and so $q$ divides $q'g$.

If $q'\ne0$, then $q$ does not divide $q'$ and so $q$ divides $g$, which implies that $q^2$ divides $f$.

If $q'=0$, then $q(x)=Q(x^p)=Q(x)^p$, where $p$ is the characteristic of $F$, and so $f$ has a multiple factor $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have common root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ in $F$, then $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$ for some $g(x)$. [Product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) then gives us $f'(x)=g'(x)(x-\alpha)+g(x)$. With $f'(\alpha)=0$  we see that  $g(\alpha)=0$, so $\alpha$ is also root of $g(x)=(x-\alpha)h(x)$ for some $h(x)$, so $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^2h(x)$

In general case the field $F$ may not be [algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field), so actually you have to do the proof in a [splitting field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field) of $f(x)$, where "are not coprime" means "have common linear factor". Q.E.D

Comment: Where did you use that the characteristic of $F$  does not divide the degree of $f(x)$ ?